# How to fix error: "Google.Apis.Auth: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set " for YouTubeAPI

Tags: .net-core, google-api, youtube-api, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created an HTTP trigger azure function, which holds the code (below) to upload a video to YouTube automatically. Source: (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

When I try to run the app locally using visual studio, I am getting the following error:

> Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=d601d64a-2f2c-4f8a-8053-a2f33ca21dbc)
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
>   Google.Apis.Auth: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web)
>   should be set

It looks like a Google Authentication error, but I am unsure as to how to get this fixed and I see that YouTube API does not support Service account? How can this issue be fixed, is there a get around to this? Thanks in advance.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadVideo
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            log.LogInformation("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
            log.LogInformation("==============================");

            try
            {
                await Run();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Video Processed..");

        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\test.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to use the service account to do the OAuth2 web server flow, which wont work. The correct code form creating a service account credential is as follows.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
              {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }
```

## Note

as i have mentioned in your other questions the YouTube API does NOT support service account authentication. You must use Oauth2 and i am not convinced this can be done inside of azure functions.  As there is no way to spawn the web browser window to request authorization of the user.

Comment: @DalmTo, I understand your point that it can’t be done using Azure function. If that the case, what are some other options? Basically, I am looking for a way to automatically upload videos to YouTube whenever I add a new Video on my OneDrive folder. I thought using Azure function + logic app will do the trick, but as you mentioned this approach isn’t working.

Comment: Thats my point.  The file you are uploading needs to be in the same place as the code is running from i have never been able to create a stream of any kind pointing to another server.  (i tried file stored in google drive) Now that you have stated its only your account you want to access. The auth issue can be gotten around by authenticating your code once on your machine and uploading the credentials file (its stored in appdata) and feeding it directly to your code though a custom iDataStore.  I created something like that for a client several years ago.

Comment: @DalmTo, is there some instructions on how to do that? Doesn’t sound so direct to me.

Comment: Here is a collection of [iDatastores](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf) i created.  And here is the tutorial i wrote on how its connected [File datastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)  Doing this is not direct at all.   Find the file get your function to read the file, upload the file to the server.  and it "should" work.  But thats not going to help you get access to the file stream from Onedrive Love to here if you get that to work though.